# getting username of logged in user

Tags: php, session

I want to get the username of logged in user so that I can insert it to database along with my form so that I can associate the data being inserted with the user logged in.. any idea?

```
    <?php 
require_once("models/config.php");
securePage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label  for="file"><font  size="5"><b>Choose Photo:</b></font></label>
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="file_selected = true;" required><br>
Last Name:<input  type="text" name="fname" required><br> 
Last Name:<input  type="text" name="lname" required><br> 
Age:<input type="text" name="age" required><br>
<input id="shiny" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Here is my Insert query..as you can see, I didn't specifiy any value for `$username` that's my problem what should I put there?

```
$photo= "pictures/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];
$age   =$_POST["age"];
$username = ?
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO photos (Firstname, Lastname, Age, author) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

// TODO check that $stmt creation succeeded

// "s" means the database expects a string
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $photo, $fname, $lname, $age, $username);

$stmt->execute();


$stmt->close();

$mysqli->close();
```

and here is what I have inside config.php...

```
<?php
require_once("db-settings.php"); //Require DB connection

//Retrieve settings
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, name, value
FROM ".$db_table_prefix."configuration");   
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $value);

while ($stmt->fetch()){
$settings[$name] = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'value' => $value);
}
$stmt->close();

//Set Settings
$emailActivation = $settings['activation']['value'];;
$mail_templates_dir = "models/mail-templates/";
$websiteName = $settings['website_name']['value'];
$websiteUrl = $settings['website_url']['value'];
$emailAddress = $settings['email']['value'];
$resend_activation_threshold = $settings['resend_activation_threshold']['value'];
$emailDate = date('dmy');
$language = $settings['language']['value'];
$template = $settings['template']['value'];

$default_hooks = array("#WEBSITENAME#","#WEBSITEURL#","#DATE#");
$default_replace = array($websiteName,$websiteUrl,$emailDate);

if (!file_exists($language)) {
$language = "models/languages/en.php";
}

if(!isset($language)) $langauge = "models/languages/en.php";

//Pages to require
require_once($language);
require_once("class.mail.php");
require_once("class.user.php");
require_once("class.newuser.php");
require_once("funcs.php");

session_start();

//Global User Object Var
//loggedInUser can be used globally if constructed
if(isset($_SESSION["userCakeUser"]) && is_object($_SESSION["userCakeUser"]))
{
$loggedInUser = $_SESSION["userCakeUser"];
}

?>
```

Comment: How do you log the user in in the first place? You need to know their username to authenticate them, just use that.

Answer (score 2):

When the user logs in, why not save it as a Session variable, then access that?

For example:

```
//Login page
//After user is authenticated

session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username 

//$username is whatever you grabbed as the supplied login details
```

Comment: the session is already started at the bottom of config.php...when i try to start it tells me that session is already started....

Comment: @alte Right, I'm just saying, wherever you log the user into, save the username in the session.

Comment: This was the simple solution I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I think from your code you would use

```
$loggedInUser = $_SESSION["userCakeUser"];
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand:
You need to add additional column to your table 'photos', the column name will be: userid not username, because its better to depend on the key-id for the user not the name.

then, like any other insert, add the new column to the query.

For now, you can try with your current option, add username field to the table, and the value is: $_SESSION["userCakeUser"];

Comment: Just one question: do you want to link username with the record? if yes: then do you created username column (field) to that table?

Comment: that's it..all I want is to to link the record with the username..What I created author column...so the username will be inserted to author column...

Comment: try to print out $_SESSION (its an array) use simple print_r($_SESSION) and then search for loggedinuser, if its there or not.

Comment: How about this: print_r($this -> Session -> read()); that mentioned : [here](http://www.justkez.com/understanding-cakephp-sessions/)

Comment: I am unable to do what I wanted...I get Catchable fatal error: Object of class loggedInUser could not be converted to string error

Comment: what did you tried? print_r($_SESSION) or print_r($this -> Session -> read()); ? please explain?